# How can I make this question answerable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

This question: [A large planet composed of all natural elements is created. What happens?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/160402/a-large-planet-composed-of-all-natural-elements-is-created-what-happens)

## How can I make this question answerable?

Basically, I just wanted to know what would happen if dozens of elements were placed together in equal mass, I wanted to know what would happen over the course of billions of years. I only added many specifications in there to avoid being too broad, but the question ended up being put on hold anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking

> What happens in this situation?
>
> What happens immediately after this mass forms?
>
> What happens over a million years?
>
> Over a billion years?

For starters, those are 4 questions, and we want 1 question per post. Then, answering each of them would take an entire university class, at least, if you had specified what you are looking for.

But, and this makes things worst, you didn't. You just asked what happens.

What happens to what? Geology? Weather? Numismatic? Ermeneutics? History of furniture crafting technique?

Basically you are asking one of the questions clearly listed in our [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) under "which question should I avoid asking?"

> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

If you can remove all those issues than your question becomes answerable according to our standards.

Comment: Ah damn, you're right. This is one of those moments where I already know the rules,  but I guess I got excited about my question and so my mind slipped.